# Spring Mongodb fetch data using DBRef association

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mongodb

I have a retailer class with nested dbref of Address. I would like to fetch retailers based on city which is part of Address class. But I am getting below error.

> org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Invalid path
>   reference address.city! Associations can only be pointed to directly
>   or via their id property!

Could you please let me know what's wrong and how to fix this?

Code is given below

```
@Document(collection="retailer")
@TypeAlias("retailer")
public class Retailer extends CommonDomainAttributes implements Serializable {

    public Retailer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @DBRef
    private List<Product> products;

    private String shopName;

    @DBRef
    private Address address;
}

@Document(collection="address")
@TypeAlias("address")
public class Address extends CommonDomainAttributes implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8820483439856446454L;


    private String addrLine1;
    private String addrLine2;
    private String locality;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
}
```

I am using following query to get the data

```
@Override
    public List<Retailer> findRetailersByProductNameAndCity(String productName,
            String city) {
        Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where/*("product.productName").is(productName).and*/("address.city").is(city));

        //BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery("{ product.productName : { $eq : '"+productName+"' }, address.city : { $eq : '"+city+"' }}");

        //System.out.println(basicQuery.toString());

        //query.fields().include("user");
        //query.fields().include("address");

        List<Retailer> retailers = mongoTemplate.find(query, Retailer.class);
        return retailers;
    }
```

Data

```
db.retailer.find().pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55eb14e077c8f563fb2c11ab"),
    "_class" : "retailer",
    "createDate" : ISODate("2015-09-05T16:14:24.489Z"),
    "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2015-09-05T16:14:24.489Z"),
    "createdBy" : "UnAuntenticatedUser",
    "lastModifiedBy" : "UnAuntenticatedUser",
    "user" : DBRef("IdeaRealtyUser", ObjectId("55eb14e077c8f563fb2c11aa")),
    "products" : [
        DBRef("product", ObjectId("55eb14e077c8f563fb2c1193")),
        DBRef("product", ObjectId("55eb14e077c8f563fb2c1194")),
        DBRef("product", ObjectId("55eb14e077c8f563fb2c119a"))
    ],
    "address" : DBRef("address", ObjectId("55eb14e0a1fd2e78e05053c2"))
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55eb14e077c8f563fb2c11ad"),
    "_class" : "retailer",
    "createDate" : ISODate("2015-09-05T16:14:24.561Z"),
    "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2015-09-05T16:14:24.561Z"),
    "createdBy" : "UnAuntenticatedUser",
    "lastModifiedBy" : "UnAuntenticatedUser",
    "user" : DBRef("IdeaRealtyUser", ObjectId("55eb14e077c8f563fb2c11ac")),
    "products" : [
        DBRef("product", ObjectId("55eb14e077c8f563fb2c1193")),
        DBRef("product", ObjectId("55eb14e077c8f563fb2c1194")),
        DBRef("product", ObjectId("55eb14e077c8f563fb2c119b")),
        DBRef("product", ObjectId("55eb14e077c8f563fb2c119f")),
        DBRef("product", ObjectId("55eb14e077c8f563fb2c11a0"))
    ],
    "address" : DBRef("address", ObjectId("55eb14e0a1fd2e78e05053c1"))
}
```